# Can someone use my phone as a proxy?

Tags: privacy, proxy

I was recently contacted by someone who claimed my phone had logged into their snapchat. Upon checking it was indeed my phone, all the details and IP matched. But I didnt log into their snapchat and am confident no one else had my phone at the time. Is it possible my phone is being used as a proxy?

Comment: For sure! with the appropiate malware, anything can be done!

Comment: *someone* Who says this person is legit?

Comment: I'd be very cautious in dealing with this person. You have to ask yourself how this person could have figured out that it was your phone that logged into their snapchat. This would usually involve a fairly amazing piece of detective work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. One built-in way is the "WiFi tethering" functionality, where you share your 4G internet connection over WiFi.

Another possibility is that some app or malware is being used to proxy network connections through your phone.